# Net Core ILogger Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, nunit

I am receiving Logger Value cannot be null. I am trying to resolve this, maybe something with dependency injection. The error is received at the Unit test and everywhere else in the program. Am I conducting dependency injection correct?

```
Expected: <System.ArgumentException>
But was:  <System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
  Parameter name: logger
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger,
                     LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception,
                     String message, Object[] args)
```

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using ElectronicsStore.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ElectronicsStore.Service
{
    public class ParseVendorSupply
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ParseVendorSupply(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public VendorSupply FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            VendorSupply vendorsupply = new VendorSupply();

            try
            {
                string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
                if (values.Length > 3)
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException("Too much data");
                }

                vendorsupply.VendorId = Convert.ToInt16(values[0]);
                vendorsupply.ProductId = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
                vendorsupply.Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(values[2]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("An exception was thrown attempting");
            }
            return vendorsupply;
        }       
    }
}

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _logger = logger;
 }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory().AddConsole().AddDebug());
     services.AddLogging();
```

**NUnit Test:**

```
public class ParseVendorSupplyNunit
{

    ILogger logger;

    //conducting this gives me an error, since cannot create instance of abstract class, not sure what alternative is
    //ILogger logger = new ILogger();

    [Test]
    public void FromCsv_ParseCorrectly_Extradata()
    {
        string csvLineTest = "5,8,3,9,5";
        ParseVendorSupply parseVendorSupplytest = new ParseVendorSupply(logger);
        //VendorSupply vendorsupply = parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest);
        Assert.That(() => parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest), Throws.ArgumentException);
    }
```

Comment: You have initialized your `logger` instance nowhere in the unit test class.

Comment: You need to initialized your `logger` instance somewhere in the unit test class

Comment: You have to construct an object of a concrete type, not an interface, either pick one of the concrete types that implement the interface or implement a dummy logger for testing purposes. You can also use mocking tools such as Rhinomocks or NSubstitute to provide an implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to initialize the `logger` variable with either an implementation of `ILogger` like `ConsoleLogger` or something similar. At the moment you aren't assigning any value to your test `logger` variable.

I would recommend passing in a mock of the logger because you're unit testing and probably don't want to test the logger itself. So use [FakeItEasy](https://fakeiteasy.github.io/) or some other Mocking-Libary and create a faked instance over `A.Fake<ILogger>()`

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the null object pattern here. Allow the `ILogger` parameter to be null, but default the field to `NullLogger.Instance` if the parameter is null. That means that you can safely use the dependency in any scenario but it doesn't force anyone to pass an instance in. Read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@cfdevelop/ilogger-and-null-object-pattern-9481eb4d8cc7).